# Objective-C - Program received signal: “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”. with (NSNumber floatValue)

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, floating-point, nsnumber

I am getting a `Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.` when using the following code.

`searchResultFileSize` is declared as an `NSNumber` in my interface. I wasn't sure what property to set it as. Currently I have it as:

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSNumber *searchResultFileSize;
```

Is this correct? I get the errors on the following lines:

```
NSLog(@"float filesize: %f", [searchResultFileSize floatValue]); //Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
HUD.progress = [resourceLength floatValue] / [searchResultFileSize floatValue]; //Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
```

If I comment out the first line it still obviously fails on the second. Any ideas what the problem could be? Perhaps my conversions are wrong. Here are the two methods where I am using this piece of code:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    [responseData setLength:0];

    searchResultFileSize = [NSNumber numberWithLongLong:[response expectedContentLength]];

    NSLog(@"Float filesize: %f", searchResultFileSize);

    if ([searchResultFileSize intValue] != NSURLResponseUnknownLength) {
        HUD.mode = MBProgressHUDModeDeterminate;
        HUD.labelText = @"Getting Results";
    }
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [responseData appendData:data];

    NSNumber *resourceLength = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:[responseData length]];
    NSLog(@"resourceData length: %d", [resourceLength intValue]);
    NSLog(@"filesize: %d", searchResultFileSize);
    NSLog(@"float filesize: %f", [searchResultFileSize floatValue]); //Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
    // HUD.progress is a float
    HUD.progress = [resourceLength floatValue] / [searchResultFileSize floatValue]; //Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
    NSLog(@"progress: %f", [resourceLength floatValue] / [searchResultFileSize floatValue]);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
searchResultFileSize = [NSNumber numberWithLongLong:[response expectedContentLength]];
```

You need to `retain` it to keep it around, it is autoreleased.

```
searchResultFileSize = [[NSNumber numberWithLongLong:[response expectedContentLength]] retain];
```

I would suggest setting your property as `(nonatomic, retain)`, then you won't have to `retain` it in your code. Plus, you should use the property setters (`self.searchResultFileSize = x;`) as opposed to direct assignment. Then you'd invoke `release` in `-dealloc`.

Also,

```
NSLog(@"Float filesize: %f", searchResultFileSize);
```

`searchResultFileSize` is a `NSNumber` object, you can output the value of an `NSNumber` using the `%@` format specifier:

```
NSLog(@"Float filesize: %@", searchResultFileSize);
```

Comment: Or, even better: `NSLog(@"filesize: %@", searchResultFileSize);`

Comment: ..and what about doing the division on HUD.progress?

Comment: As per Jacob's reco, just retain NSNumber and you will be alright.

Comment: Worked perfectly when I retain NSNumber. Thanks heaps! Should I be releasing this in my dealloc?

Comment: @Fulvio Yes, you should `release` the `searchResultFileSize` in `-dealloc`

Comment: What if I do a [searchResultFileSize release]; after I set the HUD.progress property? Is that okay too?

Comment: @Fulvio Come to think of it, that would be better.

Comment: If I do this after I set HUD.progress do I still need to release it in my dealloc. I've always been confused about that part. Also should my property be (nonatomic, retain) as well?

Comment: @Fulvio, I would suggest setting your property as `(nonatomic, retain)`, then you won't have to `retain` it in your code. Plus, you should use the property setters (`self.searchResultFileSize = x;`) as opposed to direct assignment. Then you'd invoke `release` in `-dealloc`.